# If statement inside a for loop doesn't working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I tried to return a value inside a simple for loop if a certain condition fulfills. But it's not working.

It's a very simple code:

```
function c()
{
    for(var i=5;i>-1;i++)
    {
          if(i==2)
          {
          return i;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you start at 5 and increment upwards...how can `i` ever be 2?

Comment: Change i++ to i--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't there be an i-- instead of i++?

```
function c()
{
    for(var i = 5; i > -1; i--)
    {
          if(i == 2)
          {
              return i;
          }
    }
}
```